# integrate to Ubuntu server and windows server12

Tags: server

i have windows server 12 and ubuntu 14.4 server, actually we want to get the  ubuntu server user details  throw windows server 12 system , that means one application installed windows server 12 that application we have to give a permission to access ubuntu server users so please let me know how will i configure ,

this is 2 server working on same network .

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achive. What should the Windows users access on Ubuntu server ?

Comment: Neither really get what you want but I guess you could use automated SSH connections to read Infos from the servers

Comment: soren A :  i want to integrate Ubuntu server throw window server 12 , when i am searching Ubuntu server user name in windows server 12 , i want to get the users